# How to reset canvas path style?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have creating functions to draw canvas shapes and lines like fallowing code:

```
    function drawBaseline(ctx, lineLeft, lineTop, lineEndLeft, strockWidth, strockColor) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth   = strockWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = strockColor;
        ctx.moveTo(lineLeft, lineTop);
        ctx.lineTo(lineEndLeft, lineTop);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function drawDashedLine(ctx, lineLeft, lineTop, lineEndLeft, strockWidth, strockColor, lineDash) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.setLineDash(lineDash);
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
        ctx.moveTo(lineLeft, lineTop);
        ctx.lineWidth   = strockWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = strockColor;
        ctx.lineTo(lineEndLeft, lineTop);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
```

But when I calling `drawBaseline` after `drawDashedLine`, is drawing dashed too.

```
    drawDashedLine(ctx, 0, lineTop, 300, 5, 'red', [5, 20]);
    drawBaseline(ctx, 0, lineTop, canvas.width, 1, 'black');
```

How to can I reset context reset to draw new object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slow method but lazy one is to call [`ctx.save()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) before you set the path styles then [`ctx.restore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore) when you're done.

But this will save **all** the properties of your context, and probably a lot you didn't touched (`fillStyle`, `strokeStyle`, transformation-matrix, clipping area, `globalAlpha`, gCO, dashOffset, lineCap, font, text-align ... : **all of them**).
Moreover, if for whatever reason you forget to call `restore()` after a `save()`, the saved states will accumulate in memory, which is bad.

```js
function drawBaseline(ctx, lineLeft, lineTop, lineEndLeft, strockWidth, strockColor) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = strockWidth;
  ctx.strokeStyle = strockColor;
  ctx.moveTo(lineLeft, lineTop);
  ctx.lineTo(lineEndLeft, lineTop);
  ctx.stroke();
  // now restore all properties
  ctx.restore();
}

function drawDashedLine(ctx, lineLeft, lineTop, lineEndLeft, strockWidth, strockColor, lineDash) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.setLineDash(lineDash);
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.moveTo(lineLeft, lineTop);
  ctx.lineWidth = strockWidth;
  ctx.strokeStyle = strockColor;
  ctx.lineTo(lineEndLeft, lineTop);
  ctx.stroke();
  // now restore all properties
  ctx.restore();
}

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var lineTop = 100;

drawDashedLine(ctx, 0, lineTop, 300, 5, 'red', [5, 20]);
drawBaseline(ctx, 0, lineTop, canvas.width, 1, 'black');
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

The recommended way is then to **set every property you've modified back to their default**.
(in your case `ctx.strokeStyle ="#000"; ctx.lineWidth=1; ctx.setLineDash([]);`)

```js
function drawBaseline(ctx, lineLeft, lineTop, lineEndLeft, strockWidth, strockColor) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = strockWidth;
  ctx.strokeStyle = strockColor;
  ctx.moveTo(lineLeft, lineTop);
  ctx.lineTo(lineEndLeft, lineTop);
  ctx.stroke();
  // now reset all set properties to their defaults
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
}

function drawDashedLine(ctx, lineLeft, lineTop, lineEndLeft, strockWidth, strockColor, lineDash) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.setLineDash(lineDash);
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.moveTo(lineLeft, lineTop);
  ctx.lineWidth = strockWidth;
  ctx.strokeStyle = strockColor;
  ctx.lineTo(lineEndLeft, lineTop);
  ctx.stroke();
  // now reset all set properties to their defaults
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
  ctx.setLineDash([]);
}

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var lineTop = 100;

drawDashedLine(ctx, 0, lineTop, 300, 5, 'red', [5, 20]);
drawBaseline(ctx, 0, lineTop, canvas.width, 1, 'black');
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```